# Display tickets closed using T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have come up with a script to display open and closed tickets per individual.

```
SELECT        s.displayname AS ASSIGNEE, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'open' THEN 1 END) AS [OPEN], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS CLOSED
FROM            dbo.t_helpdeskassignees AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e ON s.UserID = e.currentlyat
GROUP BY s.displayname
```

result achieved....

[image]

I want to move a step further to display same result when I filter by date but I'm not getting anywhere.

My Original query (without count function and group by) with the output

```
SELECT s.displayname AS ASSIGNEE, 
       e.status AS STATUS,
       e.lastStatusUpdate
FROM dbo.t_helpdeskassignees AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e ON s.UserID = e.currentlyat

ASSIGNEE    STATUS  UPDATEDATE
Patrick     Closed          11/26/2019
Patrick     Closed          11/25/2019
Patrick     Closed          11/28/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/25/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/26/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/26/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/27/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/27/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/27/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/27/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/27/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/28/2019
Roselant    Closed          11/28/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/25/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/25/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/25/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/25/2019
Josephat    Open            11/26/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/27/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/27/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/27/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/27/2019
Josephat    Closed          11/27/2019
Sila    Closed          11/25/2019
Isaac   Closed          11/25/2019
Isaac   Closed          11/27/2019
Isaac   Closed          11/27/2019
Isaac   Closed          11/27/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/25/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/25/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/25/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/27/2019
Elizabeth   Open            11/26/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/27/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/27/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/27/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/28/2019
Elizabeth   Closed          11/28/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/25/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/25/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/26/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/26/2019
Damaris     Open            11/26/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/27/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/27/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/27/2019
Damaris     Open            11/27/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/28/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/28/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/28/2019
Damaris     Closed          11/28/2019
Davis   NULL    NULL
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Closed          11/27/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/28/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/28/2019
Dorcas  Open            11/28/2019
```

When i ammend my query this way, i don't get any values.

```
SELECT        s.displayname AS ASSIGNEE, e.lastStatusUpdate AS UPDATEDATE, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'open' THEN 1 END) AS [OPEN], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS CLOSED
FROM            dbo.t_helpdeskassignees AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e ON s.UserID = e.currentlyat
WHERE e.lastStatusUpdate = CAST('2019-11-28 10:24:14.000' AS DATE)
GROUP BY s.displayname, e.lastStatusUpdate
```

Comment: Those dates aren't in your sample data, where are they coming from?

Comment: @Larnu from my original query which i have shown. The issue am struggling with is how to still get total OPEN and CLOSED tickects when I apply 'e.lastStatusUpdate' filter on my first query

Comment: You need to provide us with Sample data that actually shows us what your data looks like, and that data needs to be **`text`**, *not* an image. We can't help you get from A to B, when you've only told us where B and C are.

Comment: the data is in text format. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count the status at the selected date. 
You should move the date filter to the left join.

```
SELECT
    s.displayname AS ASSIGNEE,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'open' THEN 1 END) AS [OPEN], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS CLOSED
FROM
    dbo.t_helpdeskassignees AS s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e ON s.UserID = e.currentlyat
                         AND e.lastStatusUpdate BETWEEN CAST('2019-11-28 10:24:14.000' AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY,1, CAST('2019-11-28 10:24:14.000' AS DATE))
GROUP BY 
    s.displayname
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. Now CAST('2019-11-28 10:24:14.000' AS DATE) returns nothing when it should be returning something. What is the acceptable date format for this case.

Comment: values in lastStatusUpdate column date or datetime?

Comment: datetime but when i cast as date I'm still not able to see filtered data

Comment: If it is datetime then you should filter it with `between`. I made an update for this.